# How to find last instance of underscore in string?

Tags: batch-file, find

I am looking for a solution to check if a file exists already in a directory before attempting to import it. I have the script:

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do if exist "D:\Check\%%a" ( 
    del "%%a" 
) else ( 
    move "%%a" "D:\Import" 
)
```

Which is fine when I am checking the full file name. However, in this instance I want to check up to the final underscore character:

Full file name is for example: `940_20150330_12345_000288.csv.  The number of "_" in the file will vary, most will have three but some will have 4, 5, 6 or 7.

I want to delete any files found in the `Check` directory which match `940_20150330_12345*.csv` and if no files are found, then move to the import directory.

I am not sure what I need to do to replace in `for %%a in (*.csv)` in order to find up to the last underscore.

Comment: I don't think you don't want to delete "940_20150330_12345*.csv", because that would also delete "940_20150330_123456_xyz.csv"

Answer (score 0):

If your files are always of the form given (four components separated by underscores) then you could try something like:

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do if exist "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_*.csv" (
    del "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_*.csv"
    del "%%a"
) else (
    move "%%a" "D:\Import"
)
```

For each of the `.csv` files, it runs a second `for` command that extracts the first three underscore-separated components and tests to see if any files starting with those components are in the `Check` directory, deleting them and the original or moving the original to the `Import` directory as appropriate.

**Edit**

If you've got a Windows-version of `sed` around, then you could use:

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do for /f %%b in ('echo "%%a" ^| sed "s/\(.*\)_[^_]*.csv/\1/"') do if exist "%%b_*.csv"
...
```

which replaces each file name with the bit before "underscore + string-not-containing-underscores + .csv", which essentially picks the bit before the last component.

If you don't have this (it's available in several places; I've got a copy with the `Git` command-line tools), then the best I can think of so far is to have several loops, starting with the longest number of components:

```
REM check 7 underscores
for %%a in (*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*.csv) do for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do if exist "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f_%%g_%%h_*.csv" (
    del "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f_%%g_%%h_*.csv"
    del "%%a"
) else (
    move "%%a" "D:\Import"
)
REM check 6 underscores
for %%a in (*_*_*_*_*_*_*.csv) do for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do if exist "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f_%%g_*.csv" (
    del "D:\Check\%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%f_%%g_*.csv"
    del "%%a"
) else (
    move "%%a" "D:\Import"
)
REM ...etc...
```

where you reduce the number of `*_*_*...` components, the number of `tokens` and the number of `%%a_%%b_...` bits each time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments however, the filename can vary in the number of underscores, therefore I always need to go up to the last instance, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't think of a clean way, without using external tools.  Will add some options.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below solve your problem if the filenames have the form of your example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set fileName=%%~Na
   for %%b in (!fileName:_= !) do set lastPart=%%b
   set fileName=%%a
   for %%b in (!lastPart!) do if exist "D:\Check\!filename:_%%b.csv=*.csv!" ( 
       del "%%a" 
   ) else ( 
       move "%%a" "D:\Import" 
   )
)
```

This method will fail if the filenames have spaces, comma or semicolon. It also eliminate exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I convert `_` into `\` and use a 2nd FOR loop with # in front and get the resultant fake "path", ignoring the "name". I need the leading `\#` just in case there was no `_`, or if the original name began with `_`.

I strip off the leading `\#`.

If the result is undefined, then the file had no, `_` and I simply check to see if the full name exists.

If there is a result, then I convert `\` back into `_` and then perform two IF EXIST tests. One for "EverythingUntilLastUnderscore_*.csv", and another for "EverythingUntilLastUnderscore.csv"

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "check=D:\Check\"
set "import=D:\Import"
for %%A in (*.csv) do (
  set "found="
  set "file=%%A"
  for %%B in ("\#!file:_=\!") do set "base=%%~pB"
  set "base=!base:~2!"
  if defined base (
    set "base=!base:\=_!"
    if exist "!check!!base!*%%~xA"      set found=1
    if exist "!check!!base:~0,-1!%%~xA" set found=1
  ) else (
    if exist "!check!%%A" set found=1
  )
  if defined found (
    del "%%A"
  ) else (
    move "%%A" "%import%"
  )
)
```